# [react-native]update RN to 0.43.3 build failed

Tags: android, react-native

when I update RN from 0.41 to 0.43.3,I suffered a crazy problem, if I run gradlew assembleRelease, the apk build failed, but when I add option --debug, the apk build successful, it should be the problem of progurad, but i cannot fix it, any help is appreciated:

```
-gradlew assembleRelease
...
Loading dependency graph, done.easeJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
bundle: start
bundle: finish
bundle: Writing bundle output to:xxx\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\release\index.android.bundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output
bundle: Copying 5 asset files
bundle: Done copying assets

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to process incoming event 'ProgressComplete ' (ProgressCompleteEvent)
```

if I run gradlew assembleRelease --debug

```
-gradlew assembleRelease --debug
...
[LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

run gradlew assembleRelease --info or --stacktrace all failed, no warning messages show.

When i build apk use android studio,it shows:

```
    Initializing...
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIProp'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'sun.misc.Unsafe'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'android.text'
Note: com.facebook.common.webp.WebpSupportStatus: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.webpsupport.WebpBitmapFactoryImpl
Note: com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.factory.AnimatedFactoryProvider: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.factory.AnimatedFactoryImplSupport
Note: com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.factory.AnimatedFactoryProvider: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.factory.AnimatedFactoryImpl
Note: com.facebook.imagepipeline.nativecode.WebpTranscoderFactory: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.imagepipeline.nativecode.WebpTranscoderImpl
Note: okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform: can't find dynamically referenced class com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl
Note: okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform: can't find dynamically referenced class org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl
Note: okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl
Note: com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputManager accesses a declared field 'mCursorDrawable' dynamically
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.drawee.drawable.ForwardingDrawable { void setTransformCallback(com.facebook.drawee.drawable.TransformCallback); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.drawee.drawable.TransformCallback'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.drawee.view.DraweeView { void setHierarchy(com.facebook.drawee.interfaces.DraweeHierarchy); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.drawee.interfaces.DraweeHierarchy'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.drawee.view.DraweeView { void setController(com.facebook.drawee.interfaces.DraweeController); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.drawee.interfaces.DraweeController'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.drawee.view.GenericDraweeView { GenericDraweeView(android.content.Context,com.facebook.drawee.generic.GenericDraweeHierarchy); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.drawee.generic.GenericDraweeHierarchy'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.ImageRequest { ImageRequest(com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.ImageRequestBuilder); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.ImageRequestBuilder'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.animated.EventAnimationDriver { EventAnimationDriver(java.util.List,com.facebook.react.animated.ValueAnimatedNode); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.animated.ValueAnimatedNode'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleSpec { ModuleSpec(java.lang.Class,javax.inject.Provider); }', but not the descriptor class 'javax.inject.Provider'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.ModuleHolder { ModuleHolder(java.lang.String,boolean,boolean,boolean,javax.inject.Provider); }', but not the descriptor class 'javax.inject.Provider'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatShadowNode { void collectState(com.facebook.react.flat.StateBuilder,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.StateBuilder'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatShadowNode { void setNodeRegion(com.facebook.react.flat.NodeRegion); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.NodeRegion'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatTextShadowNode { void performCollectAttachDetachListeners(com.facebook.react.flat.StateBuilder); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.StateBuilder'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatUIViewOperationQueue$DetachAllChildrenFromViews { FlatUIViewOperationQueue$DetachAllChildrenFromViews(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatUIViewOperationQueue); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatUIViewOperationQueue'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatUIViewOperationQueue$ViewManagerCommand { FlatUIViewOperationQueue$ViewManagerCommand(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatUIViewOperationQueue,int,int,com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatUIViewOperationQueue'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewManager { void setBackgroundColor(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup,int); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewManager { void removeAllViews(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.RCTImageViewManager { RCTImageViewManager(com.facebook.drawee.controller.AbstractDraweeControllerBuilder,java.lang.Object); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.drawee.controller.AbstractDraweeControllerBuilder'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.RCTImageViewManager { void removeAllViews(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.RCTImageViewManager { void setBackgroundColor(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup,int); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.RCTTextInput { long measure(com.facebook.yoga.YogaNodeAPI,float,com.facebook.yoga.YogaMeasureMode,float,com.facebook.yoga.YogaMeasureMode); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.yoga.YogaNodeAPI'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.RCTTextManager { void removeAllViews(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.RCTTextManager { void setBackgroundColor(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup,int); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.RCTViewManager { void setHotspot(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup,com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.RCTViewManager { void receiveCommand(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup,int,com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.RCTViewManager { void setNeedsOffscreenAlphaCompositing(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.RCTViewManager { void setPointerEvents(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup,java.lang.String); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.RCTViewManager { void setRemoveClippedSubviews(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.RCTViewManager { void setHitSlop(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup,com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.RCTViewManager { void removeAllViews(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.RCTViewManager { void setBackgroundColor(com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup,int); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.FlatViewGroup'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.flat.RCTVirtualText { void performCollectAttachDetachListeners(com.facebook.react.flat.StateBuilder); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.flat.StateBuilder'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.modules.core.Timing { com.facebook.react.modules.core.Timing$IdleCallbackRunnable access$1202(com.facebook.react.modules.core.Timing,com.facebook.react.modules.core.Timing$IdleCallbackRunnable); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.modules.core.Timing$IdleCallbackRunnable'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.AlertFragment { AlertFragment(com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.DialogModule$AlertFragmentListener,android.os.Bundle); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.DialogModule$AlertFragmentListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.SupportAlertFragment { SupportAlertFragment(com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.DialogModule$AlertFragmentListener,android.os.Bundle); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.DialogModule$AlertFragmentListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.FrescoModule { FrescoModule(com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext,com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineConfig); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineConfig'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.ReactNetworkImageRequest { com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.ReactNetworkImageRequest fromBuilderWithHeaders(com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.ImageRequestBuilder,com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.ImageRequestBuilder'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.ReactNetworkImageRequest { ReactNetworkImageRequest(com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.ImageRequestBuilder,com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.ImageRequestBuilder'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.SystraceRequestListener { void onRequestStart(com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.ImageRequest,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.ImageRequest'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.SystraceRequestListener { void onRequestSuccess(com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.ImageRequest,java.lang.String,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.ImageRequest'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.SystraceRequestListener { void onRequestFailure(com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.ImageRequest,java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.ImageRequest'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.modules.image.ImageLoaderModule { void registerRequest(int,com.facebook.datasource.DataSource); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.datasource.DataSource'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.shell.MainPackageConfig$Builder { com.facebook.react.shell.MainPackageConfig$Builder setFrescoConfig(com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineConfig); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineConfig'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager { void manageChildren(int,int[],com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewAtIndex[],int[]); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewAtIndex'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyOptimizer { NativeViewHierarchyOptimizer(com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue,com.facebook.react.uimanager.ShadowNodeRegistry); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.uimanager.ShadowNodeRegistry'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyOptimizer { void handleManageChildren(com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNode,int[],int[],com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewAtIndex[],int[]); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewAtIndex'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue { void enqueueManageChildren(int,int[],com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewAtIndex[],int[]); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewAtIndex'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager { void addEventEmitters(com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext,com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayout); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayout'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager { void setDrawerPosition(com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayout,int); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayout'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager { void getDrawerWidth(com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayout,float); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayout'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager { void setDrawerLockMode(com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayout,java.lang.String); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayout'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager { void setElevation(com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayout,float); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayout'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager { void receiveCommand(com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayout,int,com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayout'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager { void addView(com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayout,android.view.View,int); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayout'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageManager { ReactImageManager(com.facebook.drawee.controller.AbstractDraweeControllerBuilder,java.lang.Object); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.drawee.controller.AbstractDraweeControllerBuilder'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageView { ReactImageView(android.content.Context,com.facebook.drawee.controller.AbstractDraweeControllerBuilder,java.lang.Object); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.drawee.controller.AbstractDraweeControllerBuilder'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageView { void setScaleType(com.facebook.drawee.drawable.ScalingUtils$ScaleType); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.drawee.drawable.ScalingUtils$ScaleType'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageView { void setControllerListener(com.facebook.drawee.controller.ControllerListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.drawee.controller.ControllerListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarShadowNode { long measure(com.facebook.yoga.YogaNodeAPI,float,com.facebook.yoga.YogaMeasureMode,float,com.facebook.yoga.YogaMeasureMode); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.yoga.YogaNodeAPI'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager { void setStyle(com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarContainerView,java.lang.String); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarContainerView'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager { void setColor(com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarContainerView,java.lang.Integer); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarContainerView'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager { void setIndeterminate(com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarContainerView,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarContainerView'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager { void setProgress(com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarContainerView,double); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarContainerView'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager { void setAnimating(com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarContainerView,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarContainerView'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager { void updateExtraData(com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarContainerView,java.lang.Object); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarContainerView'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager { void onAfterUpdateTransaction(com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarContainerView); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarContainerView'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager { void setEnabled(com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitch,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitch'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager { void setOn(com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitch,boolean); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitch'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager { void setThumbTintColor(com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitch,java.lang.Integer); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitch'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager { void setTrackTintColor(com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitch,java.lang.Integer); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitch'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager { void addEventEmitters(com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext,com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitch); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitch'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageShadowNode { FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageShadowNode(com.facebook.drawee.controller.AbstractDraweeControllerBuilder,java.lang.Object); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.drawee.controller.AbstractDraweeControllerBuilder'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageSpan { FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageSpan(android.content.res.Resources,int,int,android.net.Uri,com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap,com.facebook.drawee.controller.AbstractDraweeControllerBuilder,java.lang.Object); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.drawee.controller.AbstractDraweeControllerBuilder'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageViewManager { FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageViewManager(com.facebook.drawee.controller.AbstractDraweeControllerBuilder,java.lang.Object); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.drawee.controller.AbstractDraweeControllerBuilder'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactEditText { void setSelectionWatcher(com.facebook.react.views.textinput.SelectionWatcher); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.react.views.textinput.SelectionWatcher'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputShadowNode { long measure(com.facebook.yoga.YogaNodeAPI,float,com.facebook.yoga.YogaMeasureMode,float,com.facebook.yoga.YogaMeasureMode); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.yoga.YogaNodeAPI'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.react.views.toolbar.DrawableWithIntrinsicSize { DrawableWithIntrinsicSize(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,com.facebook.imagepipeline.image.ImageInfo); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.imagepipeline.image.ImageInfo'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.yoga.YogaBaselineFunction { float baseline(com.facebook.yoga.YogaNodeAPI,float,float); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.yoga.YogaNodeAPI'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.facebook.yoga.YogaMeasureFunction { long measure(com.facebook.yoga.YogaNodeAPI,float,com.facebook.yoga.YogaMeasureMode,float,com.facebook.yoga.YogaMeasureMode); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.facebook.yoga.YogaNodeAPI'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.imagepicker.ImagePickerModule { void putExtraFileInfo(java.lang.String,com.imagepicker.ResponseHelper); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.imagepicker.ResponseHelper'
Note: there were 3 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 78 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
Note: there were 7 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 1 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
      (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
```

how to modify my proguard file?

Comment: I got that error as well on react ^15.4.2 and react-native 0.43, but upgrading to 16.0.0-alpha.6 fixed it. So id say.. stay away from 0.43 or use react 16.0.0-alpha.6

Comment: I have modified the proguard file,and now there are still 'duplicate' message: Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate]...Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpParams]Note: there were 7 duplicate class definitions.how to remove these duplicate classes?

Comment: @cityvoice did you manage to solve it ? I have the same issue.